# Change colour names in custom word theme

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, customization, branding

Im looking for a solution that may not exist but worth a try.  I am currently making custom modifications to normal.docm to incorporate our corporate branding.  We have successfully created a new colour theme with our corporate colours but would like to know if we can change the names of these colours in the tool tip when you hover over in the colour picker.

[Word colour picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPOwQ.jpg)

We have specific names for each of the colours which are know throughout are brand guidlines.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the name of theme colours from Accent 1, Accent 2 etc. simply isn't possible.